# How can I bypass error code 429 on discord when sending a request?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How can I bypass error code 429 when I am sending a request on discord. Is there any work arounds for node.js

I tried to send alot of requests but now I am rate limited.

Comment: There are typically two ways out of a rate limit: Time and money. Ie lower the number of requests or (if available) buy a subscription for a better tier which provides an increased rate limit ...

Comment: Discord doesn't offer a premium tier for their API – but you can probably reach out to them to request an increase if #1 the bot isn't violating their TOS and #2 it has a LOT of users and hits the ratelimit even when your code is optimized to avoid these ratelimits.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Otherwise you will spam the API. And that just [isn't very good.](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/bots/what-is-rate-limiting/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).